# "Yielding" in laravel without whitespace?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

In laravel you can do this:

```
@section('metadescription')
   description goes here... 
@stop
```

But this results in:

```
 <meta name="description" content=" XXXXXXXXX ">
```

I don't want those spaces. Is there a way to specify only a set of parameters that also get trimmed on being yielded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
@section('metadescription'){{ "Description goes here" }}@stop
```

Comment: This is also helpful when you need to @overwrite some sections in different templates extending the same partial https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/extending-the-same-layout-in-two-partials

Answer (score 13):

If you're only passing simple strings to the section, you can pass the string as a second argument to the `section`. For example:

```
@section('metadescription', 'Meta Description goes here')
```

Comment: I put a @stop on the next line also. Pretty sure it's not required, but I like seeing it there.